# Apple rejected my app because of non-public APIs springboard

Tags: ios, cross-platform, nativescript

I use Nativescript, my app was rejected by Apple many times by the issue below.
Can someone please help me.

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> com.apple.springboard.hasblankedscreen
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> If you are using third-party libraries, please update to the most
>   recent version of those libraries. If you do not have access to the
>   libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using
>   the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can
>   output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov"
>   will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined
>   methods. These tools can help you narrow down where the problematic
>   code resides. You could also use the "nm" tool to verify if any
>   third-party libraries are calling these APIs.

Comment: don't use it, it is referencing apple springboard

Comment: But I have used it, I cannot change, it will take so much effort.

Comment: I guess you will have to do those efforts else your app may not get pass through apple review process

Comment: You need to plan that thing first before you try to add it to App Store

Comment: @nhatduy I understand the frustration of building something and having to re-write it. But there is literally nothing anyone can do. You are not allowed to do something you have done, there is no question about it you have to remove the feature or find another way to do what ever it is you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have accepted my app after I removed one of libraries.
In my case, I used a SDK from my supplier of bluetooth door. It is old version so it call non-public API. Thank you all anyway.